# Smooth covers pulling back a cohomology class to any algebraic multiple

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology

Fix an algebraic integer $x\neq 0$. Does there exist a closed smooth manifold $M$ with a class $\rho\in H^{1}_{\mathrm {dR} }(M)$ and a smooth covering map $\phi:M\to M$ such that $\phi^*\rho=x\rho$?

Comment: Did you really mean to ask about covering maps $M\to M$, or covering maps $\widetilde M\to M$? I strongly suspect the answer is negative in the former case; in the latter I'm not so sure.

Comment: @MarkGrant: In the latter case, the equation $\phi^*\rho = x\rho$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MarkGrant it's $M\to M$

Comment: This means that $x$ is an eigenvalue of a matrix with integer entries, hence an algebraic integer.

Comment: @PhilTosteson thank your for your remark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every nonzero algebraic integer $x$ in $\mathbb R$  is an eigenvalue of an $\mathbb R$-diagonalizable integer matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb Z)$ with $\det(A) \neq 0$ for some $n$.   So take the map of tori $A^t: \mathbb R^n /\mathbb Z^n \to \mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$.  This acts by $A^t$ on $\mathbb Z^n = H_1(\mathbb R^n /\mathbb Z^n)$ and hence by $A$ on $H^1(\mathbb R^n /\mathbb Z^n)$.

Comment: Not quite! Only algebraic integers of norm $\pm 1$ occur this way.

Comment: Thanks @Qiaochu-- I shouldn't have said $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$  (I was trying to be too brief).  I think everything works the same when $det(A) \neq 0$.

Comment: I guess the result is just a nontrivial covering map so yes.